# How to create a GUI for my program

Tags: python, user-interface, py2exe

I have created a very (very) simple program for taking French words, then opening a tab to a French Dictionary.

```
#Made by Will Bishop with help from cdonts
import webbrowser
import sys
trans = True
n = 1
while trans == True:
    if n > 1:
        s = input('Another one: ')
    if n == 1:   
        s = input('French Word/Sentence: ' )
    if n < 1:
        print('I am not entirely sure how this happened, but isn\'t this embarrasing')
    s = (s.lower())
    word = ("".join(c for c in s if c.isalpha() or c in " '"))
    list = word.split()
    lang = 'fren'
    for word in list:    
        webbrowser.open('http://www.wordreference.com/' + (lang) + '/' +       (str(word)))
    n = n + 1
```

Then using Py2EXE I managed to get it into an EXE file, and have now made an installer. But I really want a GUI before I give this program to people. I want to try and use Tkinter but I am not sure I could implement my code into Tkinter to have a GUI for my program rather then a DOS-Style program.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to implement a GUI into your program. [Here is a link to a Tkinter tutorial from TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm). Any additional problems you have can likely be solved by searching the issue or looking up a tutorial on YouTube.